# how to restart cursor from last end point

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

how can i restart this cursor after `if` condition and want row_number start from one again in answer.want to restart cursor from end point of if condition.

```
  declare @SUM DECIMAL(20,2)
  declare @EMPCODE varchar(10)
  declare @NETPAY DECIMAL(10,2)
  declare ABC scroll cursor for 
  select EMPCODE,NETPAY from TXXL where DATE='04-30-2015'
  open ABC
  declare @TEMP table(
  EMPCODE varchar(10) primary key,
  NETPAY DECIMAL(10,2),
  SUM  varchar(max)
   )

  set @SUM=0
  fetch first from ABC into @EMPCODE,@NETPAY

  while @@fetch_status=0

  begin

  fetch next from ABC into @EMPCODE,@NETPAY

  SET @SUM=@SUM+@NETPAY


  if(@SUM<=900000)



  insert into @TEMP(EMPCODE,NETPAY,SUM) values(@EMPCODE,@NETPAY,@SUM)



  end

  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPCODE) ROWNUMBER,EMPCODE,NETPAY,SUM from @TEMP
close ABC
deallocate ABC
```

this cursor gives that answer,cursor stop working after `000179` EMPCODE because the sum of next empcode is greater than `900000` i want to start next empcode with ROWnumber `1` and sum like that the sum of this sample :-

```
ROWNUMBER   EMPCODE NETPAY      SUM
       1    000066  29079.00    29079.00
       2    000076  34515.00    63594.00
       3    000084  15493.00    79087.00
       4    000090  30399.00    109486.00
       5    000109  25812.00    135298.00
       6    000111  31453.00    166751.00
       7    000113  30408.00    197159.00
       8    000116  28040.00    225199.00
       9    000124  27901.00    253100.00
       10   000128  24445.00    277545.00
       11   000131  35760.00    313305.00
       12   000141  23345.00    336650.00
       13   000150  48965.00    385615.00
       14   000179  39350.00    424965.00
```

want answer like that:-

```
  ROWNUMBER EMPCODE NETPAY      SUM
       1    000066  29079.00    29079.00
       2    000076  34515.00    63594.00
       3    000084  15493.00    79087.00
       4    000090  30399.00    109486.00
       5    000109  25812.00    135298.00
       6    000111  31453.00    166751.00
       7    000113  30408.00    197159.00
       8    000116  28040.00    225199.00
       9    000124  27901.00    253100.00
       10   000128  24445.00    277545.00
       11   000131  35760.00    313305.00
       12   000141  23345.00    336650.00
       13   000150  48965.00    385615.00
       14   000179  39350.00    424965.00
        1   000181  40814.00    40814.00
        2   000182  24335.00    65149.00
        3   000196  29439.00    94588.00
        4   -----    ------      -------
        5   -------- -----      -------
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that we don't have your tables nor your data. I've no idea what you're trying to achieve here. Could you add some sample data and expected results to your question please?

Comment: Hi.  Here is the MSDN help page for IF statements: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182717.aspx.  CURSORS can be quite slow.  Are you sure this is the way to go?  Perhaps if you could provide some sample data and a sample output we could help you find a better approach.